# Ways of object recognition in computer vision

Tags: classification, pattern-recognition, computer-vision

In the field of computer vision, we talk a lot about this process of feature detection-description-matching as a way of recognizing objects. But on the other hand, there's also talks about object classifiers and such, but aren't they based on this feature detection description matching? 
Is detecting features and describing them and matching those descriptions the only way of recognizing objects?

Comment: This has the feel of "please survey that area" which would be too broad.

Comment: @Raphael, all I would like to know is whether there is somebody somewhere who did object recognition in a way different of detection-description-matching because that would spare me some time and it would prove to me that there are other ways of object recognition that are implemented in a complete different way, I don't ask anyone to survey anything, I am not asking for a state of the art.